# How do I transfer a running total sum to another sheet in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

Here is my problem:

Sheet1 contains a row A-I of info. I want the column of I, to sum automatically in B3 on Sheet2.

column I has data starting in I3, down. I only have a few lines of date (I10), but as time progresses I will be adding more in, and that total I would like have sum in B3 by itself, so after having 300+ lines of numbers in (1.2,4,6,.4) etc it would add up, and I can just go to sheet 2 look in B3 and see the running total from sheet 1.

I hope this makes sense

Answer (score 2):

Enter =SUM(Sheet1!I:I) in cell B3 on Sheet2.

Comment: Ok I tried that, and it doesnt work, as it shows 0, when it should show 10.9. is there something I am missing?    Also, When I put this function in("=SUM(Sheet1!I4)"  it seems to put the first number in I4 (I pushed the first row down for formatting) into the total on sheet 2. So I have that figured out, just not sure why it wont add I5,I6,I7 and so on.

Comment: @Rotorhead212 you don't want `SUM` of `I4`, you want `SUM` of `I:I`